# Download PHP and CSS from the Wordpress admin page without FTP

Tags: ftp

Some of my clients don't have CPanel access to their WordPress, so I have to copy and paste from the built-in editor to pull out the PHP.

Is there a way within that admin interface to grab all the PHP files? I don't have FTP acces.. gr...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should demand access to ftp or the command line, working without is is crippling and to be blunt, silly.

Comment: That's what I figured. I've opted not to work for the client unless he upped the ante quite a bit for my frustration. Thanks!